# Get values of Selected ListView Item WinJS

Tags: javascript, listview, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am wanting to grab the values (type_of_service, picture) of the item that was selected in my ListView. servicesList.selection.type_of_service.value does not seem to be working.

```
var tosTable = client.getTable("TypeOfService");
var serviceTypes = new WinJS.Binding.List();

tosTable.orderBy("type_of_service")
    .select("type_of_service", "picture")
    .read()
    .done(function (results) {
        serviceTypes = new WinJS.Binding.List(results);
        servicesList.winControl.itemDataSource = serviceTypes.dataSource;
    });

var Service = WinJS.Class.define(
    function (type_of_service, picture) {
        this.type_of_service = type_of_service;
        this.picture = picture;
    },
    {
        _type_of_service: undefined,
        _picture: undefined
    }
);

servicesList.addEventListener("selectionchanged", function () {
    var selectedService = new Service(servicesList.selection.type_of_service.value,
        servicesList.selection.picture.value);

        WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/orgs/orgs.html");
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
servicesList.winControl.itemDataSource = serviceTypes.dataSource;
```

Makes me think that "servicesList" is your ListView DOM element, not the ListView itself. So if you want to get the selection you should change your code from servicesList.selection to use servicesList.**winControl**.selection.

One other thing is the selection can be multiple items so it's not just a data item, but an ISelection interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872204.aspx

So you'll have to do something like:

```
var selection = servicesList.winControl.selection;
if(selection.count()) {
    selection.getItems().then(function(items) {
        // do something with the selected item
        console.log(items[0].data); 
    }
}
```